# Переключение видео файлов после окончания

Tags: javascript, html5

Здравствуйте! У меня есть один элемент `video`. Как мне по завершению одного переключить его на другое? И можно ли сделать, что бы когда закончилось последнее видео, то включалось первое?

Мой код:

```js
var videos = [
  "https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos_dashhd/C40B136F021365174982178762752_53f4484ad8e.25.1.ADDA1E67-CF16-4C3B-901A-DE068DE26134.mp4",
  "https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos_h264dash/9E0C561D561232222781018615808_3ae4ac8f321.4.2.559218590213998566.mp4",
  "https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos_h264dash/640E862C-1279-4B1B-89DD-1CC8BD0003A3-121-0000003319090DC5_1.0.6.mp4",
  "https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos_h264dash/00A2889BFD1101390404009553920_148f4f22224.3.2.mp4?versionId=7DBWwt94N5zgF2gU6wjrBD84KJ_Q5s4b"
];

// Как переключать?
```

```css
video {width: 100%; height: 300px;}
```

```html
<video src="https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos_dashhd/C40B136F021365174982178762752_53f4484ad8e.25.1.ADDA1E67-CF16-4C3B-901A-DE068DE26134.mp4" controls="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для переключения существует функция `onended`, которая вызывается после завершения видео.

Я немного усовершенствовал ваш список видео и написал маленький скриптик. Его в ходе нужно будет вам доработать:

```js
var videos = {
  'videos_list_0': [
    "https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos_dashhd/C40B136F021365174982178762752_53f4484ad8e.25.1.ADDA1E67-CF16-4C3B-901A-DE068DE26134.mp4",
    "https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos_h264dash/9E0C561D561232222781018615808_3ae4ac8f321.4.2.559218590213998566.mp4",
    "https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos_h264dash/00A2889BFD1101390404009553920_148f4f22224.3.2.mp4?versionId=7DBWwt94N5zgF2gU6wjrBD84KJ_Q5s4b"
  ]
};

(function() {
  var video = document.querySelectorAll('video[data-videolist]');
  
  for(var i = 0; i < video.length; i++){
    var n = video[i].hasAttribute('data-video') ? Number(video[i].getAttribute('data-video')) : 0,
        r = video[i].getAttribute('data-reiteration') == 'true' ? true : false,
        ap = video[i].getAttribute('data-autoplay') == 'true' ? true : false,
        vl = video[i].hasAttribute('data-videolist') ? video[i].getAttribute('data-videolist') : null;
    if(videos[vl]){
      video[i].src = videos[vl][n];
      if(ap){
        video[i].play();
      };
      video[i].video = n;
      video[i].onended = function() {
        if(this.video == videos[vl].length - 1){
          if(r){
            this.video = 0;
            this.src = videos[vl][0];
            this.play();
          };
        }else{
          this.video = this.video + 1;
          this.src = videos[vl][this.video];
          this.play();
        };
      };
    }else{
      console.error('Undefined video list!');
    };
  };
}());
```

```css
video {width: 100%; height: 300px;}
```

```html
<video data-videolist="videos_list_0" data-video="0" data-reiteration="true" data-autoplay="true" controls="">
```

P.S. у вас третье видео было битое и по этому я его удалил :)