# как слелать чтобы после окончания видео перекидывало автоматически на второе видео?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребят есть две кнопки , при нажатии на первую кнопку открывается первое видео. Соответственно при нажатии на вторую кнопку открывается второе видео , как сделать чтобы при нажатии на первую кнопку и после окончания его видеофайла автоматически перекидывалось событие на вторую кнопку и открывалось второе видео ?

```
<div id="content">
        <video class="videoContent" id="video" autoplay ></video>
        <div class="but-link_1" data-video="resources/1.mov" id="first" checked="checked"></div> /// первый див с видео
        <div class="but-link_2" data-video="resources/2.mov" id="second"></div> // второй div с видео
    </div>
```

Добавил вот эти Js строчки но не помогло.

```
 document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended',smoothly,false)
    function smoothly(e) {
        document.getElementById('first').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('second').checked = true;
        document.getElementById('second').checked = "checked";
    }
```

Comment: Anton, вот тут уже есть решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633783/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подпишитесь на окончание видео и вызовите второе видео.

```
<video src="video.ogv" id="myVideo">
  video not supported
</video>

<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
function myHandler(e) {
    // What you want to do after the event
}
</script>
```

Код взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/detect-when-an-html5-video-finishes)

Comment: а можно по подробей что писать в функции

Comment: @Anton, `document.getElementById('myVideo').src = 'новая ссылка на видео'; document.getElementById('myVideo').play();`

Comment: @Yuri что то не получилось , я написал так теперь просто второе видео запускается первым

Comment: @Yuri там в решениях немного другое, в моем решении нужно чтобы было так: автоматически воспроизводится первое видео, а дальше после окончания переход к следующему видео. видео связаны в диве класса but-link_1 и but-link_2